# Mountain Lion always switches to previous application at wake up

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

Since upgrading to Mountain Lion (from Snow Leopard), I have noticed that always when I wake up my MacBook Pro, a window from the previously active application is moved to the front.

What causes this?
Can I turn this "feature" off?

Comment: FWIW, I had this problem [long before Mountain Lion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21142/mid-2011-macbook-air-changes-applications-on-wake-from-sleep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Daniel Lawson for pointing to the solution:

The issue is cause by the 'require password after sleep or screen saver begins' option in the system security settings. If you turn this off, the issue disappears.